# xml, three attribute, one of them is required

Tags: xml, dtd

want to know if it possible in dtd to make of tree attribute required, but when one is used all other become optional :

```
<!ELEMENT train (CDATA) >

<!ATTLIST train seconds CDATA #REQUIRED !>
<!ATTLIST train minutes CDATA #REQUIRED !>
<!ATTLIST train hours CDATA #REQUIRED !>
```

I want to know how to make, when one is used the other attributes become optional

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think this is possible, not even using a schema.

Comment: Make them all optional, enforce the complicated interaction in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply rules like that using DTD alone. You would have to use `#IMPLIED` in all attributes as suggested, and deal with that restriction in your code.

XML Schema 1.0 doesn't support that either, unless you use a standard extension such as Schematron, which allows assertions via XPath.

You can do that in XML Schema 1.1 using assertions (`<xs:assert>`, very similar to Schematron, although you might have trouble finding a parser which supports it.